# read he snmp sent by the manager

Tags: snmp, agent

im looking everywhere for a solution and my head is burning..
im new to snmp , ill explain abit what im doing and what im expecting to get..

so im building a project which will send a getsnmp to HYTERA repeater and retrieve details, upon that ill know if its alive and other stuff aswell..

all i want (and i guess thats not so simple) is to be able to read the OID that the manager sent me...

in the agent i want a python code that can wait for a request and print "hey i got it" just to know that its possible and that i can make some conditions..

please help me

Comment: What exactly are you trying to build? An SNMP agent? Or an SNMP manager? If you cannot describe that clearly, I doubt anyone can help.

Comment: an snmp agent, that can read the request sent to him by the manager